# Turbogears: duplicate controller method for filtered objects

Tags: python, turbogears2

If you have a controller method like so:

```
@expose('example.templates.example.index')
def index(self, *args, **kw):
    fruits=session.query(model.Fruit).all()
    # some code working on fruits
    return dict(fruits=fruits)
```

How can I duplicate the method for the same html rendering but with filtered objects like example

```
@expose('example.templates.example.index')
def filtered(self, name="apple", *args, **kw):
    fruits=session.query(model.Fruit).filter_by(name=name).all()
    # some code working on fruits (same as in index)
    # how to not duplicate the code but duplicate method with different input fruits?
    return dict(fruits=fruits)
```

how to not duplicate the code but duplicate only method with different input fruits?
I wish to have separate endpoints working the same but with filtered input.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a subcontroller with the `_default` method?

See https://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/turbogears/objectdispatch.html#the-default-method

At that point you could do

```
class FruitsController:
    @expose('example.templates.example.index')
    def _default(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        fruits=session.query(model.Fruit).filter_by(name=name).all()
        return dict(fruits=fruits)

class RootController:
    fruits = FruitsController()
```

The result will be that when you ask for `GET /fuits/apple` you will get back only apples, and `GET /fruits/banana` will only give you back bananas and so on... You can also provide a default argumento `name=None` in case you want to allow `GET /fruits` to just return all fruits.